# JavaScript function call context has valid parameters, but function doesn't get them

Tags: javascript, function, callback

In a custom event-handling setup using callbacks, the calling context of the callback shows valid values for the callback parameters, but the argument values are undefined after stepping into the function.

In case it matters, this is inside of an Electron renderer process which uses React.

In a vanilla JavaScript object, the debugger shows expected contextual values for everything on the line of the callback reporting `SerialPortEvent.Opened`.

```
// file: serialPort.js (no imports)
class SerialPortEvent {
  Discovered = 0
  Opened = 1
  Closed = 2
  DataReceived = 3
  Error = 4
}

class SerialPortSpec {
...
  addEventListener(listener) {
    this.listeners.push(listener)
  }

  open(baudRate) {
    const baudRateInt = parseInt(baudRate, 10)

    window.serialport.open(this.portInfo.path, baudRateInt)
      .then(binding => {
        this.baudRate = baudRateInt
        this.binding = binding

        // Here, the debugger shows all locals are as expected

        this.listeners.forEach(listener => listener(SerialPortEvent.Opened))
      }).catch(reason => {
        this.listeners.forEach(listener => listener(SerialPortEvent.Error, reason))
      })
  }
...
}

...

module.exports = { SerialPortEventHub, SerialPortSpec, SerialPortEvent }
```

However, one "step into" later, at the beginning of the callback function "portEventHandler", the argument values are `undefined`. I would love to know why! Thanks.

```
// file SerialPortUI.jsx

import React from 'react'
import { SerialPortEventHub, SerialPortEvent, SerialPortSpec } from './serialPort'
import './serialportui.css'

class SerialPortPanel extends React.Component {
...
  portEventHandler(eventType, ...data) {
    // Here, eventType is undefined. This file does import SerialPortEvent.
    switch (eventType) {
      ...
    }
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `addEventListener`?

Comment: @Unmitigated it is called in SerialPortPanel's componentDidMount() function. The reference to it is visible while debugging the SerialPortSpec instance's listeners list.

Comment: In my experience, this is often related to circular dependencies. Show us where the SerialPortEvent is defined, and how it is exported. Include also how it is imported in your code. If you have it inside of one of the files which the above code is contained within, it could be an indicator of a problem if those files also import each other.

Comment: @adsy thanks, I have edited the post to clarify that the data model file does not import the relevant React file. I wrote the vanilla data model first following the traditional pattern, but  I believe my next step will be to merge that state into the React classes instead if this doesn't get figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> class SerialPortEvent {
>   Discovered = 0
>   Opened = 1
>   Closed = 2
>   DataReceived = 3
>   Error = 4
> }
> ```

That's not a proper enum declaration. Class fields will be created on an instance, the static class property `SerialPortEvent.Opened` you are accessing in your code is indeed `undefined`. And that's the value the called function receives.

Instead, you'll want to use an object with properties:

```
const SerialPortEvent = {
  Discovered: 0,
  Opened: 1,
  Closed: 2,
  DataReceived: 3,
  Error: 4,
};
```

Never use `class` syntax if you don't ever instantiate it (use `new`)!

Comment: He could also use `enum` in TS which is pretty much the only thing that has a runtime in TS

Comment: @adsy Yes, I was originally going to suggest in a comment that `class` might have been confused with `enum`, but the question is not tagged with TypeScript

Comment: Ah yes that's right, for some reason my mind was parsing it as TS when there is no TS there.